# Saving in Laravel returns empty with no error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created an API using Laravel and uploaded it Heruko free webhosting. But when I use the API and added some data on the database I will get a return of `[]` . But this is working fine on my local.

***Here's my saving code***:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $listing = Listings::create($request->all());
        
        $details = new Listings($request->input()) ;

        $currentUser = Listings::find(0);
        $file = $request->company_logo;
        $filename = basename($file);
            
        // dd($details);
         $details->splid                = $request->splid;
         $details->listing_type_id      = $request->listing_type_id;
         $details->manage_level_id      = $request->manage_level_id;
         $details->price_setting_id     = $request->price_setting_id;
         $details->user_id              = $request->user_id;
         $details->is_featured          = $request->is_featured;
         $details->disable_claim        = $request->disable_claim;
         $details->rating               = $request->rating;
         $details->listing_title        = $request->listing_title;
        //  $details->company_logo          = $request->company_logo;
         $details->company_slogan       = $request->company_slogan;
         $details->listing_email        = $request->listing_email;
         $details->url_type             = $request->url_type;
         $details->listing_url          = $request->listing_url;
         $details->listing_display_url  = $request->listing_display_url;
         $details->listing_phone        = $request->listing_phone;
         $details->listing_fax          = $request->listing_fax;
         $details->listing_address1     = $request->listing_address1;
         $details->listing_address2     = $request->listing_address2;
         $details->listing_zipcode      = $request->listing_zipcode;
         $details->listing_summary      = $request->listing_summary;
         $details->listing_description  = $request->listing_description;
         $details->listing_keyword      = $request->listing_keyword;
         $details->listing_location     = $request->listing_location;
         $details->hours_of_work        = $request->hours_of_work;
         $details->listingservice_id    = $request->listingservice_id;
         $details->countrie_id          = $request->countrie_id;
         $details->countryname          = $request->countryname;
         $details->state_id             = $request->state_id;
         $details->statename            = $request->statename;
         $details->citie_id             = $request->citie_id;
         $details->cityname             = $request->cityname;
         $details->lat_value            = $request->lat_value;
         $details->lng_value            = $request->lng_value;
         $details->vid_url_type         = $request->vid_url_type;
         $details->embedded_code        = $request->embedded_code;
         $details->video                = $request->video;
         $details->attached_file        = $request->attached_file;
         $details->promotional_code     = $request->promotional_code;
         $details->renewal_date         = $request->renewal_date;
         $details->status               = $request->status;
         $details->extraloc             = $request->extraloc;
         $details->paid_status          = $request->paid_status;
         $details->add_transaction      = $request->add_transaction;
         $details->backlink             = $request->backlink;
         $details->seo_title            = $request->seo_title;
         $details->seo_friendly_url     = $request->seo_friendly_url;
         $details->seo_description      = $request->seo_description;
         $details->seo_keywords         = $request->seo_keywords;
         $details->facebook_url         = $request->facebook_url;
         $details->twitter_url          = $request->twitter_url;
         $details->googleplus_url       = $request->googleplus_url;
         $details->instagram_url        = $request->instagram_url;
         $details->pinterest_url        = $request->pinterest_url;
         $details->linkedin_url         = $request->linkedin_url;
         $details->slug                 = $request->slug;
         $details->latupdate            = $request->latupdate;
         $details->rankid               = $request->rankid;
         $details->sortdate             = $request->sortdate;
         $details->abn                  = $request->abn;
         $details->apiid                = $request->apiid;
         $details->owner_name           = $request->owner_name;
         $details->owner_emailaddress   = $request->owner_emailaddress;
         $details->owner_phonenember    = $request->owner_phonenember;
         $details->addresshide1         = $request->addresshide1;
         $details->addresshide2         = $request->addresshide2;
         $details->created              = $request->created;
         $details->modified             = $request->modified;
        //  $details->listing_schema       = $request->listing_schema;
         $details->is_paid_addon        = $request->is_paid_addon;
         $details->is_paid_logo         = $request->is_paid_logo;
         $details->is_paid_video        = $request->is_paid_video;
         $details->logo_renewal_date    = $request->logo_renewal_date;
         $details->video_renewal_date   = $request->video_renewal_date;
         $details->view_flag            = $request->view_flag;
         $details->created_at           = $request->created_at;
         $details->updated_at           = $request->updated_at;

        //$data_id = $details->id;
        $details->company_logo = $filename;
        $details->save();
               
                $folder = public_path('images/' . $details->id . '/');
                File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
                $location = public_path('images/' . $details->id . '/');
                Image::make($file)->resize(800,400)->save(public_path('images/' . $details->id . '/' . $filename));
         
        $category = $listing->categories()->create([
            'category_id' => $request->input('category_id')
        ]);


        return response()->json(['message' => 'Added Successfully']);


    }
```

***Note:*** all requested data  are fillable in model.

Comment: you should return the saved category not only the message, return response()->json(['message' => 'Added Successfully','category'=> $category]);

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your problem :

You can replace all of your line `$details->_____ = $request->_____;`
by `$details->fill( $request->all() );`
or `$details->fill( $request->only(['splid', 'listing_type_id', ...]) );`

Your controller will be smaller and more human-readable.

---

PS: I d'ont understand this part :

```
$listing = Listings::create($request->all());
$details = new Listings($request->input());
...
$details->save();
```

Why create two `Listings` with your request datas ?